# Change into name attribute in <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change name attribute in `<input>` element, I have in the here several name `string[0][]`, now i want after click on link add change ‍‍`0` in they and replace `1` instead all `0`. How is it by Jquery?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2hXk5/

I try as but don't work for me:

```
<div class="ch">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cFE[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cFE[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cFE[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cFE[0][]">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cYG[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cYG[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cYG[0][]">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cYG[0][]">
    </p>
    <a href="" class="adding">Add</a>
</div>
​


$('a.adding').live('click change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $clone = $(this).closest('.ch').clone().insertAfter('.ch');
    $clone.find('input[type="checkbox"]:contains("0")').prop('1');
})​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) with a callback function:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name',function(i,str) {
    return str.replace('0','1');
});
```

UPDATE: Here's a complete version which will do everything you seem to actually want. It uses `str.match(/\d+/)` to extract the FIRST number-string in the `name` attribute, converts it to an integer, then replaces it with the next integer using `str.replace`. Note the `insertAfter` part was updated so it only inserts after the LAST `div.ch`:

```
$(document).on('click change', 'a.adding', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $div = $(this).closest('.ch');
    $clone = $div.clone().insertAfter($div);
    $clone.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name', function(i, str) {
        var int = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0],10);
        return str.replace(int, (int+1));
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3SGNw/

Comment: Updated. Check fiddle. I'm not perfectly clear what your desired result is.

Comment: `0` is dynamic in the here it just is a example.

Comment: @TaylorGomez, you need to tell people that up front!

Comment: The first got it and then changed.(0)

Comment: Change the replace line to: `return str.replace(/\d+/,function(x){ return parseInt(x,10)+1 });`

Comment: @epascarello great suggestion, but I prefer my two-line version for readability. Still, I'm gonna remember that trick.